# Programmatically change Redux-Form Field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

When I use `redux-form` v7, I find there is no way to set the field value. Now in my `form`, I have two `select` component. The second's value will be clear when the first `select` component value changed.

In class render:

```
<div className={classNames(style.line, style.largeLine)}>
  <div className={style.lable}>site:</div>
  <div className={style.content}>
    <Field
      name="site"
      options={sites}
      clearable={false}
      component={this.renderSelectField}
      validate={[required]}
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div className={classNames(style.line, style.largeLine)}>
  <div className={style.lable}>net:</div>
  <div className={style.content}>
    <Field
      name="net"
      options={nets}
      clearable={false}
      component={this.renderSelectField}
      validate={[required]}
      warning={warnings.net}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I add the `select` change hook, and how can I change the other `select` value

```
renderSelectField = props => {
  const {
    input,
    type,
    meta: { touched, error },
    ...others
  } = props
  const { onChange } = input
  const _onChange = value => {
    onChange(value)
    this.handleSelectChange({ value, type: input.name })
  }
  return (
    <CHSelect 
      error={touched && error}
      {...input}
      {...others}
      onChange={_onChange}
      onBlur={null}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can have the onChange logic in `this.handleSelectChange({ value, type: input.name })` and use [`change` action from redux-form](http://redux-form.com/7.0.0/docs/api/Props.md/#-code-change-field-string-value-any-function-code-)

According to the docs:

> **change(field:String, value:any) : Function**
>
> Changes the value of a
> field in the Redux store. This is a bound action creator, so it
> returns nothing.

Code:

```
import { change } from "redux-form";

handleSelectChange = (value, type) => {
  if (type === "site") {
    this.props.change('net', "newValue");
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({change}, dispatch);
}
```

Comment: is there an API to set multiple fields at the same time? not during initialValues

Comment: how does this work for the `component='select'` variant of `<Field>` component ?

Comment: @Dane similar to how it would work for the input field, it need the field name as the first parameter and the option's value that you need to select

Comment: Can you explain a little what happens here? why bind dispatch to change? and how change is a props method?

Comment: @shinzou, mapDispatchToProps is something that you use with connect, any action creator that needs to be called from the component need to be bind with dispatch. You can read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994197/whats-the-difference-between-mapstatetoprops-and-mapdispatchtoprops/49994253#49994253 and https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri where is the change function imported from? Do we really need to bind it to component props or reduxForm automatically does that?
in your code : bindActionCreators({change}, dispatch); , {change} is obviously undefined and should be imported from somewhere right ?

Comment: `import { change } from "redux-form";`

Comment: NOTE: the `change` from **redux-form** it's the function that does the trick (upating)

Comment: ```dispatch(change({someField: someValue})```

Comment: If you import `change` from `redux-form`, then the arguments are: `change(form: string, field: string, value: any, touch?: boolean, persistentSubmitErrors?: boolean): FormAction`

Comment: @MichaelBuen I solved it by setting the `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` setting in order to affect all fields