# mapStateToProps vs mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops, mapdispatchtoprops

What's the difference between **`mapStateToProps`** and **`mapDispatchToProps`** arguments to the `connect` function in react-redux?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is a function that you would use to provide the store data to your component, whereas `mapDispatchToProps` is something that you will use to provide the action creators as props to your component.

According to the docs:

> If **`mapStateToProps`** argument is specified, the new component will
>   subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store
>   is updated, `mapStateToProps` will be called. The results of
>   `mapStateToProps` must be a plain object, which will be merged into
>   the component’s props.
>
> With **`mapDispatchToProps`** every action creator wrapped into a dispatch
>   call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the
>   component’s props.

A simple example would be

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { addTodo: bindActionCreators(addTodo, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todos);
```

Comment: hey correct me if i am wrong but i am able to call my actions without using mapDispatchToProps like ***export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);*****, so that means it isnt neceessary right ?

Answer (score 27):

In a very simple term,

**mapStateToProps**: It connects redux state to props of react component.

**mapDispatchToProps**: It connects redux actions to react props.

A really light example: ( I hope, you know what I mean)

```
// state
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { lists: state.lists };
};

// props
const mapDispatchToProps = ({ lists }) => (
  <ul>
    { 
      lists.map(el => (
        <li key={ el.id }>
          { el.heading }
        </li>
      )
    }
  </ul>
);

// Now, connect state to prop
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps);
```

Answer (score 16):

In very simple terms:

**`mapStateToProps`** is called when you want to get the value of the global state from your component

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    message: state.message

  };
}
```

The value of the global state is only changed with the help of an action. So if you want to change the value of global state you need an action.  **`mapDispatchToProps`** is used to bind action in your component.

Comment: hey correct me if i am wrong but i am able to call my actions without using mapDispatchToProps like ***export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);*****, so that means it isnt neceessary right ?