# React & Redux: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, parceljs

I am new with `redux`, `react` and `parceljs`. I'm currently experimenting with this 3 stuff by doing the `redux tutorial`. And after `parceljs` did it job, when I went to the browser I got this error on the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function`

The code right now is

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const AddTodo = ({dispatch}) => {
.
.
.
}
export default connect()(AddTodo)
```

I changed:

`import { connect } from 'react-redux';`

to:

`import { connect } from 'redux';`

and gave me basically same error.

What should I do in this case?

I checked the documentation and issues and the only issues I found about `connect()` is that you cannot use it as a decorator but that's it. Am I missing something I don't know yet?

(Sorry for my bad grammar in English, not my first language)

Comment: AddTodo doesn't seem to be a component and you aren't supplying anything to connect. Also are you sure you have install react-redux npm package

Comment: code seems correct. Post AddTodo

Comment: it is not necessary to supply anything to connect @ShubhamKhatri isnt it?

Comment: const AddTodo = (props) =>  {} AddTodo is supposed to be like this

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, no it doesn't require any arguments but it requires a component which is binded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use connect, you need to bind the component not an object. Thus, you may change your todo

```
const AddTodo = {
```

With:

```
const AddTodo = () => { // a stateless component
 // now, you can return the object
 return ( // just an example
  <div>
   <input type="text" />
  </div>
  )
}
```

And the connect is imported from react-redux:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; // this is correct
```

Comment: My bad the AddTodo is like this:

`const AddTodo = ({dispatch}) => { ... }` 

And have the return and everything. Also, I did install `react-redux` package. and the others `connect()` are working fine. Is in that file that have been giving me problem.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994197/whats-the-difference-between-mapstatetoprops-and-mapdispatchtoprops/49994239#49994239)