# React redux Form checkbox `defaultChecked` not working

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-redux-form

```
<Field
   defaultChecked={ true }
   onChange={ this.handleFormItemRadio }
   component={ "input" }
   type={ "checkbox" }
   name="tAdmin"
/>
```

When the field is initialized, I expect it to be checked but it renders unchecked even though I am supplying a `true` value.

I was pointed to number of solutions but am still not able to solve this.

Comment: What version of redux-form are you using?

Comment: @Mrchief  "redux-form": "^7.4.2"

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializefromstate/), the prescribed way is to set `initialValues`

```
<Field
   onChange={this.handleFormItemRadio}
   component="input"
   type="checkbox"
   name="tAdmin"
/>

...

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple', // a unique identifier for this form
  initialValues: { tadmin: true },
})(SimpleForm);
```

Here's a CodeSandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2on863xwj0)

Comment: Apparently this doest work for me. And to be little more inquiry, my form has several fields with dynamic `true Or False` (from props), i dont expect to supplie each field name to `initialValues` . There should be some way to streamline that

Comment: Post your full sample in that case. You probably will have to roll your own chechkbox field.